# image overlay with ffmpeg runs the script indefinitely

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I really tried hard, I did not succeed, so I am asking here. I wanted to have an overlay image (jpg) with text on video (mp4; 15 secs) and have fade-in and fade-out for the overlayed image (and not the video). I could do this with the follwing command, but it hangs after after reaching 451 frames. After this the "drop" (shown in the output; drop=1451) starts increasing and the process never finishes.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i overlay.jpg -filter_complex \
"[1] drawtext=fontfile=$fontfile:text='TESTING TEXT':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=46:x=0:y=0 [t0]; 
[t0] fade=in:st=0:d=3 [t1]; 
[0][t1] overlay=0:900:enable='between(t,0,15)'" \
-codec:a copy output.mp4

Output:
frame=  451 fps=8.8 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4790kB time=00:00:14.98 bitrate=2619.0kbits/s dup=75 drop=1451
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

Your image input is looping indefinitely. Add `shortest=1` to your [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) to force the output to terminate when the shortest input terminates:

```
overlay=0:900:enable='between(t,0,15)':shortest=1
```

### Option 2

Remove `-loop 1`.

Comment: Thanks much. removing "-loop 1" removed the overlay as well. But adding shortest=1 worked perfectly.

Comment: @kprotocol Removing `-loop 1` does not also remove the overlay for me, but I did not try your exact command.

Comment: I am facing same problem.I have already added **shortest=1**.Still my command goes into infinite loop.error like **Invalid PNG signature**.Please provide any appreciate solution

Comment: If i remove ** loop 1** video generate with duration 0 sec.(in short not generate)